# iPad and iPhone Default to Driving Instructions in Google Maps Would Like Default to Map

Tags: ios, google-maps

For a Google Maps, a URL like this:

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=from:90210,CA,US(You)+to:New+York,NY,US(Destination)

will show the driving instructions instead of the maps. You tap the map icon to get the map. Would like it to default to the map right away. Is this possible?

On the Google Maps app, it loads as driving instructions selector, is there a way to have the map displayed too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you listed explicitely passes information to Google Maps to put it into "driving instructions" mode. So unless you use a different URL (or just plain http.//maps.google.com/) there is no way to avoid that.